# Converting SQL Server datatime format to unix time

Tags: sql-server, datetime

We are working with a JSON API that returns times in what we have been told is the SQL Server date time format, for example: /Date(-6847804800000+0000)

I'm trying to convert this into unix time to use standard methods on it, does anyone know an easy way to do this? If not, converting it into any sort of other date format would be helpful.

PS: We don't have access to the SQL Server database to change the way the API spits the data out.

Comment: -6847804800000 does not like any know datetime format in SQL Server. For starters, any value would be >0 for all dates after 01 Jan 1900. What date is this meant to represent anyway?

Comment: Hi gbn, I agree. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. This should represent 1st of january 1753 according to an XML doc we have. The minus is very confusing.

Comment: If that were miliseconds sindse 1970 you would get 01 Jan 1753

Comment: the minus means it is that many milisecond before 1970. What language are you using to convert the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service is passing out `SqlDateTime.MinValue` + the hours of the day it is talking about.

The base of 1753 is used to determine an offset value, your offset is 1970 instead.

Firstly, you want to take the returned -6847804800000 and add the total miliseconds between 1753 and 1970. This will give you the offset in from 1970.

```
        SqlDateTime minSqlDateTime = SqlDateTime.MinValue;

        DateTime minTimeStampDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

        double milli = (minTimeStampDateTime - (DateTime)minSqlDateTime).TotalMilliseconds; // = 6847804800000

        double toDetermineTicks = -6847804080000; // so this is 01/01/1753 12:00 PM

        double ActualUnixTicks = (toDetermineTicks + milli) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick check with PowerShell:

```
PS> [datetime]"1970-01-01 00:00" + [timespan]::FromMilliseconds(-6847804800000)

01 January 1753 00:00:00
```

So commenters Martin and Gerben appear to be correct. This is millisecond offset from 19700101T000000.

Comment: Just to add a little context, 1753-01-01 is the minimum value that the datetime data type can accept.  So that lends some credence to this being the correct answer.

Comment: @BenThul: True for SQL's `datetime` type but not for .NET's `DateTime` (minimum is 0001-01-01) which is matched by SQL's (2008 & 2008R2) `datetime2` type. Need to be careful about `datetime` as it is ambiguous even limited to MS products.